# Faded while used line of codes in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

After a while, Vscode (Version 1.70.1) started to show some parts of my code as faded. These parts are used in several points in my code, so they are not unused variables that are usually faded in VScode. I have downgraded VScode but the problem still exists.  I would like to know why this happened.

faded lines

[image: faded lines]

Comment: do you first see syntax highlighting and after a short while some text gets different colors (darker tint), that is the semantic highlighting, use the TextMate Scope inspector to see the semantic scopes

Comment: Thank you, then how can I get rid of it? when I disable it, still some lines are not as highlighted as others.

Comment: why does semantic highlighting mark this as different?

Comment: That is my question too.

Comment: what does the TextMate Scope say about that section

Comment: Both have the same scope which is "source.python" (I used "inspect editor tokens...", to inspect)

Comment: `np` and `var_2` have a different color so they have a different scope, what is the scope difference between the `np`'s

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand your question. Please consider var_1 and var_2, they are both numpy vectors, but var_2 is faded and darker while both are used in the code.